# Chrome Extension that saves every POST data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to make an extension that saves every post data.
I searched and found out that I need a background.js file that will do it...

What I want to know, is how to "grab" post data when it's being sent?

I couldn't find it anywhere...

Thanks!

I know that I should use chrome.webRequest.onSendHeaders But I don't know how to "grab" all the content from the post.

Answer (score 2):

It's not available to grab post data with chrome.WebRequest.*. See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91191 for the news.

Comment: webRequest is the logical place for this functionality, so if webRequest doesn't have it, it probably doesn't exist.  Consider also that several developers commented on the bug report something like, "Missing this feature is stopping us from porting our Firefox plugin to Chrome." If several developers couldn't find a workaround over the course of a year, I'm guessing no workaround currently exists.  On the positive side, the feature was marked as "started" in mid-June, so it might be coming in the next few releases.

Answer (score 1):

This is now available on the development branch of Chrome. You can access post data by checking the requestBody of a chrome.webRequest object. Google needs participants to submit their working extensions through the link below before post support can be pushed into beta and eventually a stable release.

Further details are available at the URL mentioned above:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91191

And the Google developer documentation:
http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/webRequest.html